# Store an image in localStorage

Tags: ajax, local-storage

I try to stock an image in the **localStorage** using an Ajax request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        var storedImage;
                        if (localStorage.getItem('imgtest')) {
                            storedImage = localStorage.getItem('imgtest');
                            alert("get");
                        }
                        else {
                            storedImage = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            localStorage.setItem('imgtest',storedImage);
                            alert("set");
                        }
                        document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = 'data:image/png;base64,' + storedImage;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","img.png");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","image/png");
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can store the stream, but the image is not displayed.

Maybe it is because of my encoding, I don't know.
Can you tell me what I do wrong or if there is a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with url() like this:

document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = 'url(data:image/png;base64,' + storedImage + ')';

Comment: Here is a small image, does this work ?
`<html>
<body style='background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACAQMAAABIeJ9nAAAABlBMVEX//wAAAACLx9WPAAAADElEQVQImWNwYGgAAAFEAMFvZzHgAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)'>
</body>
<html>`

Comment: It is working, but the fact is I don't have the `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACAQMAAABIeJ9nAAAABlBMVE‌​X//wAAAACLx9WPAAAADElEQVQImWNwYGgAAAFEAMFvZzHgAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC` and I search how to obtain it.

Comment: Do you need help to produce it serverside ?

Comment: Yes. I tried with an Ajax request that returns me a stream, but it seems to doesn't work. The stream look like it is compressed.

Comment: The string should be compressed but in base64. If you use php server side, you can do something like this: `echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('image.png'));`

Comment: Yes, this is what I apparently have to do. Do you know a similar function in Javascript (I have tried with btoa() but an INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR happens) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do your request with POST ?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem is not in the request on the image, I catch the same stream. The problème is to display the image with that stream.